# Brackets from Beautiful Soup impacting pystache output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mustache

I am trying to insert html code, that was parsed with Beautiful Soup, into a template with pystache (mustache) and am running into some major posting issues.

The beginning and end of the soup extract contains an opening and closing set of brackets that is killing me.

Here is my code:

```
orig_file = open(input_file, 'r')                 
template = open('template.html').read()
Beautiful Soup html parsing   
soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_file)   
main_txt = soup.find(id='main-content')          
tags = main_txt.find_all(not_inside_toc)
values = {       
    'main' : main_txt,
        }   
html_main = pystache.render(template, values)
```

Here is some of the returned code: 
[//,    ,  ,

// div.rbtoc1386636254365

I have looked everywhere and tried everything but just can't find a working solution.

Please let me know if there are questions and/or if additional info is required.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Update post print(main_txt):

Within the Aptana console window print(main_txt) is the desired code sans brackets and it looks good. Though when I run it through a command window I receive a crash with print(main_txt) due to an encoding error. Can that be a hint?

Update 2: I have not seen anything to use instead of the Beautiful Soup and pystache combo, at least in the short window that I have. In hindsight other templating solutions should have been looked at to handle this project. I have overlooked some requirements based on the ease of use. But ease of use doesn't help much if it doesn't provide you with what you need.

So are there some good Beautiful Soup and pystache alternatves?

Comment: When you print out main_txt what do you get?

My first though was that it was tags causing the problem as that will return a list but you don't seem to be using it.

Comment: THANKS for the response, DasSnipez!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question by the old reliables of trial and error and RTFM.

All that was needed was a simple conversion of the soup find to a str. I was trying that, but in the wrong place.

Here is the new line:

main_txt = str(soup.find(id='main-content'))

It was one if those simple fixes that can allow you to learn a lot about a subject. In this case, it was Beautiful Soup and pystache for me.

Comment: You should use `soup.find(id='main-content').get_text()`

Comment: @justhalf: Thanks, but get_text() will not help me since the html tags are required.

Comment: I see, I didn't notice that.